# Python - Croniter - Exactly 5 or 6 columns has to be specified for iteratorexpression

Tags: python, cron

I have this script:

```
import croniter
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

def main():

    f = open("/etc/crontab","r")
    f1 = f.readlines()
    for x in f1:
        cron = croniter.croniter(x, now) 
        cron.get_next(datetime.datetime)
        print(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

With this script, I aim to read a `/etc/crontab` file, and print the next time every scheduled job will run.

However, with this script it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cron.py", line 19, in <module>
main()
File "cron.py", line 14, in main
cron = croniter.croniter(x, now) # Here!
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/rest_tails2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/croniter/croniter.py", line 92, in __init__
self.expanded, self.nth_weekday_of_month = self.expand(expr_format)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/rest_tails2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/croniter/croniter.py", line 467, in expand
raise CroniterBadCronError(cls.bad_length)
croniter.croniter.CroniterBadCronError: Exactly 5 or 6 columns has to be specified for iteratorexpression.
```

I'm brand new to croniter, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are likely things other than crontab entries in `/etc/crontab` like comments, environment variable definitions, etc.

You effectively need to only consider lines that contain actual cron patterns, something like the following:

```
import croniter
import datetime
import re

now = datetime.datetime.now()

def main():

    f = open("/etc/crontab","r")
    f1 = f.readlines()
    for x in f1:
        if not re.match('^[0-9*]', x):
            continue
        a = re.split(r'\s+', x)
        cron = croniter.croniter(' '.join(a[:5]), now)
        print("%s %s" % (cron.get_next(datetime.datetime), ' '.join(a[5:])))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output (yours will differ):

```
2018-12-02 15:17:00 root cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
2018-12-03 06:25:00 root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
2018-12-09 06:47:00 root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
2019-01-01 06:52:00 root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

Comment: Thank You very much, what I need is to also print everything as human-like, like when every crontab task/entry will be executed, that's why I'm using croniter, but I'll open a new question for that, Thank You again mate!

Comment: @NeoVe I've updated the answer to provide that output. Thanks.